# Rails 5: Merging parameters in view - where to permit them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, strong-parameters

what is the new way in Rails 5 to merge actual page query strings to link with a new one?

Let's assume I have page http://localhost:3000?type=a and I want to add another query param to the link on page:

```
<%= link_to root_path(params.merge(tech: "b")) do %>
```

but I get: *unable to convert unpermitted parameters to hash*.
Where I should permit the params?
I tried to do it in *before_action* filter, but it seems to be too late.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

My controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  before_action :permit_params

  ...

  private

  def permit_params
    params.permit(:tech, :type)
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you added `tech` as permitted parameter?

Comment: Yes I did. I've added the controller code to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to whitelist the params you want to merge with

```
<%= link_to 'Home', root_path(params.permit(:type, :tech).merge(tech: 'b')) %>
```

and get `/?tech=b&type=a`. If you *really* want all parameters, you can use [`permit!`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit-21)

```
<% params.permit! %>
<%= link_to 'Home', root_path(params.merge(tech: 'b')) %>
```

which will give you `/?action=index&controller=home&tech=b&type=a`, which while those keys don't seem to be messing anything up, is very likely not desired (and `controller` and `action` will be overridden and not passed into your controller action). NOTE: The `controller`/`action` are set that way because I'm on my `HomeController` `index` action, not because that's what `root_path` is pointing to

I just don't think I can recommend doing this, however (seems iffy, imo)...stick with whitelisting.

Comment: Ok, seems to work. Thanks! But I'd like to whitelist all the params on one place. Just `<% params.permit(:type, :tech) %>` doesn't work. Why?

Comment: The [permit](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit) returns a new instance of ActionController::Parameters, doesn't modify it in place. If you want to use the `permit_params` method you've defined you could put it in HomeHelper and then access it in the view with `permit_params` and in the controller as `helpers.permit_params` (might be better ways to do that though)